# Is a "Nerve" a cell or a tissue?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience

Nervous tissue includes Neurons and Glial cells. Neurons have soma and other projections (neurites) namely Axon and Dendrites. Axon or dendrites of a nerve cell covered with endoneurium
is called nerve fibre, a bundle of nerve fibres covered by perineurium is called
nerve fasciculus, many nerve fasciculi covered by epineurium form the "nerve". Is the "nerve", which is present in the PNS, will be regarded as a tissue or a cell?

Comment: Welcome. As far as I can see, you've answered your own question.

Comment: I'm new to the subject, can you please elaborate, if you don't mind?

Comment: What kind of response is that?

Comment: I advise you to scour google and search for "cell versus tissue" - the thing you need to get clear for yourself is the distinction between these two terms. Then this question will be answered quite easily.

Comment: I think you are clear that nerves are not cells. Your question should be more precisely: Do nerves have the propierties to be consider a tissue?